okular has stopped working after recent Horus upgrade
Okular fails to startup after a recent Horus upgrades; the syslog and running "flatpak run org.kde.okular" both give:
Qt: Session management error: Could not open network socket
QApplication: invalid style override 'adwaita' passed, ignoring it.
Available styles: Breeze, Windows, Fusion
kf.config.core: Watching absolute paths is not supported "/usr/share/color-schemes/BreezeLight.colors"
MESA: error: Failed to query drm device.
glx: failed to create dri3 screen
failed to load driver: iris
failed to open /dev/dri/card1: No such file or directory
failed to load driver: iris

Uninstalling and reinstalling via the AppCenter doesn't help, though the uninstall fails with Details "director not empty". And leaves my ".local" directory full of files with the string "okular" in it, not all of which are in ".removed".
Anyone have any suggestions? I guess I could install it using "apt" but that loads 350 Mb of dependencies.

The latest Horus update included an "Intel VAAPI Driver" update (visible in the AppCenter list of updates), but it doesn't seem to have helped. And neither has anyone else around here ...

It seems I'd turned off graphics acceleration for Okular using the Flatseal app; turned it back on and and it seems to work now.
